# Exporting result from kml package in R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means

I'm using a `kml` package of R to cluster my data and I need to get in the end a csv file with a column including the number of clusters according to each id. The data has many missing values, so I can't use `kmeans` function without deleting all observations, but `kml` works nicely with that. My problem is that I use `choice()` to export the results and all I get is a graphical window, but no output files. Here is my code:

```
setwd("/Volumes/NATASHKA/api/R files")
statadata <-read.dta("Data_wide_withdemogr_auris_for_kml_negative.dta")
mydata  <- data.frame(statadata)
cldDQ <- cld(mydata)
kml(cldDQ,c(2:6),20,toPlot="none")
plotAllCriterion(cldDQ)
par(mar = rep(2, 4))
X11(type = "Xlib")
choice(cldDQ, typeGraph = "bmp")
```

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and I solved it that way:
first, you need to choose the desired partition with the arrow
second, select it pressing “space”, 
then press “Enter” and you can find all files in your work directory, check getwd(). 
Good luck.