# Output from 'choice' in R's kml

Tags: r, output, kml, cluster-analysis, x11

I'm having trouble getting 'choice' to create output. When the graphical interface launches, I am selecting a partition with the space bar. This creates a black circle around the partition, indicating it has been selected. When I click 'return', nothing happens.

I checked my working directory to look for the output files, but they are not there. I used getwd() to ensure that I have the correct setwd(). No dice.

There was a similar question posted: [Exporting result from kml package in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16895162/exporting-result-from-kml-package-in-r); however, the answer does not work for me.

Any suggestions? I am using R 3.1.0 GUI Mavericks build(6734) and XQuartz 2.7.6. Thanks for any help getting this working.

Here is my code:

```
setwd("/Users/eightfrench")

mydata <- read.csv("hcris_long3.csv")

cldHCRIS <- clusterLongData(traj=mydata)

kml(cldHCRIS,nbClusters=2:4,nbRedrawing=2,toPlot="both")

X11(type="Xlib")

choice(cldHCRIS, typeGraph= "bmp")
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when using RStudio and i solved it just opening the x11 device with no specification. Like this:

> setwd("/Users/eightfrench")
>
> mydata <- read.csv("hcris_long3.csv")
>
> cldHCRIS <- clusterLongData(traj=mydata)
>
> kml(cldHCRIS,nbClusters=2:4,nbRedrawing=2,toPlot="both")
>
> X11()
>
> choice(cldHCRIS, typeGraph= "bmp")

Hope this also works for you.

Answer (score 1):

The new version of kml (2.3) fix that, it provide a key to export data with linux as well (not "return" since getGraphicsEvent does not accept "return" using linux, so I have to map another key : 'm')

Christophe