# ClusterLongData kml package export to scv

Tags: r, time-series, kml, export-to-csv, k-means

I am clustering time series in R using package KmL. I have read both manual and paper how to use this package, but Im not very clear how to export the results (data frame, where each trajectories are assign to some clusters e.g. 
trajectory (i),  time1, time2, time3, clustername)

I have read several answers here [Output from 'choice' in R's kml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23833654/)
but if I do the same (run choice(myCld, typeGraph= "bmp")) my R says:

```
 ~ Choice : menu ~ 'Arrow' : change partition 'Space' : select/unselect a partition ... etc.  e    : change the display (both)
 ~ 'Return' when its done ~
```

And only thing that is saved to my library is  myCld.Rdata and it runs for very long time without any more results. (my dataset: N trajectories, with time= 1:53) I want to have csv. files as manual suggest (objectName-Cx-y-Clusters.csv)

I am also not very clear WHERE should I PRESS on "Return" or "Arrow"? There is no option to press on anything in my Rstudio workplace.

I am really a beginner with R so any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that kml is compatible with Rstudio. The older version of Rstudio did not handle instruction like getGraphicsEvent that was used by choice.